# Change header date format in Pages

Tags: pages

How can I change the header date in Pages to just the year?
The only choices are different versions on the month, date and year, all together.

Comment: Just manually type it in.

Answer (score 1):

The choices that are listed here are based on what is configured within the OS. You can change this, of course.

1. Go into your **System Preferences** under 'Language & Region' and click 'Advanced…'.
2. Under the 'Dates' tab, you can change one of the formats (e.g., 'Medium') to just be the year and click 'OK'.
   [image: Custom Date Format]
3. Restart **Pages** and you should now be able to customise based on year.

[image: Date Format]

If you go to a computer that does not have this setting, it will still be the same until somebody edits the date field.